# How to save changes from two variables?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write a bash script, which checks if a new user logged in within 5 seconds, and if so, print it's details: name, username, ......
I already have the following code, which checks if a new user have logged in:

```
originalusers=$(users)
sleep 5
newusers=$(users)
if diff -u <(echo "$originalusers") <(echo "$newusers")
then
echo "Nothing's changed"
exit 1
else echo "New user is logged in"
diff -u <(echo "$originalusers") <(echo "$newusers") >shell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to find the difference between two Bash variables and keep the difference in a new variable. One possibility is to save the diff result into a variable:

```
diff_result=`diff -u <(echo "$originalusers") <(echo "$newusers")`
echo -e "diff result:\n$diff_result"
```

However, if you use this code you will still have to parse the diff result. Another possibility is to use the comm command:

```
originalusers_lines=`sed -e 's/ /\n/g' <(echo "$originalusers") | sort -u`
newusers_lines=`sed -e 's/ /\n/g' <(echo "$newusers") | sort -u`
comm_result=`comm -13 <(echo "$originalusers_lines") <(echo "$newusers_lines")`
echo -e "new users:\n$comm_result"
```

The first two lines create sorted unique lists of line separated usernames.
The comm command is used to find usernames that appear only in the new usernames list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one. It's a bash script that uses awk for counting exits and entries.

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -d '' awkscript <<EOF  # awk script is stored to a variable
BEGIN{
    split(now,n)
    split(then,t)
    for(i in n)
        a[n[i]]++
    for(j in t)
        a[t[j]]--
    for(i in a) 
        if(a[i]) 
            print i, (a[i]>0?"+":"") a[i] " sessions"
}
EOF
while true                  # loop forever
do
    sleep 1                 # edit wait time to your liking
    then="$now"
    now="$(users)"
    awk -v then="$then" -v now="$now" "$awkscript"
done
```

Run it:

```
$ bash script.sh
james 14 sessions  # initial amount of my xterms etc.
james +1 sessions  # opened one more xterm
james -1 sessions  # closed one xterm
```

Really didn't have any place to test it with lots of users coming and going.